# install phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, 20.04, lamp, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with install phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 20.04. I have an error:

> An error occured while installing the database

Error is like [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04) but I can't fix that. This article said that I must disabled Valdiate Password component. So I tryed wrote

```
UNINSTALL COMPONENT "file://component_validate_password";
```

But command UNINSTAL doesn't exist. How can I solve my problem?